# How to consolidate GET request stats in locust

Tags: locust

Locust seems to be consolidating the request stats based on endpoint, this works fine for POST request because endpoint doesn't change. However, for GET request endpoint can change on every request

```
ex, 
xyz.com/v1/user/<user_id1>
xyz.com/v1/user/<user_id2>
```

In this case standard stats that we get are not consolidated at entire test level, what we get in the standard report is

```
xyz.com/v1/user/<user_id1> | request latency details 
xyz.com/v1/user/<user_id2> | request latency details
```

This is not helpful when we have to assess the entire load test. is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `name` parameter to rename your requests.

```
self.client.get("/v1/user/" + user_id, name="/v1/user/...")
```

for details see https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#name-parameter